# T-SQL count in time interval and find the highest frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to build query which shows and count the most frequent product in transactional data. In this case we could have a multiple lines of a product for a certain day, but the query should take into consideration the whole data.

For instance, from the data below, we could see that product "tablet" is the most popular product, with the most sales. However we could also observe that this item has been sold in only 2 days out 7.

On the other hand product "cleaner" has been sold everyday from the beginning to the end of data.

Sum of the appearances could not work in this case, because some product could be in a high demand for a one day, but havent been bought any for the next five days. The query should give as a result that the "cleaner" is the product which has been bought every day.

```
Date    |Product ID|Product|QTY|Price
02.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
02.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
02.01.19|FG4549|phone      |4  |800
02.01.19|DF2345|mouse      |5  |20
02.01.19|KO4865|monitor    |1  |450
02.01.19|SDF486|coffe mach |6  |300
02.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |1  |20
03.01.19|KO4GR |surround   |2  |450
03.01.19|SDFGEA|vaccum clea|8  |300
03.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
04.01.19|HK2KOI|charger    |1  |15
04.01.19|HK2KOJ|cooler     |1  |20
04.01.19|HK2GDS|mouse pad  |10 |8
04.01.19|FG4549|phone      |4  |800
04.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |1  |20
04.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
05.01.19|49894U|chair      |1  |100
05.01.19|49894U|chair      |5  |100
05.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
05.01.19|JIPIO4|book       |1  |20
05.01.19|NGGO7|lamp        |1  |80
06.01.19|HK2KOI|charger    |1  |15
06.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
07.01.19|48961G|keybord    |11 |20
07.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
07.01.19|HRF584|headset    |2  |40
08.01.19|GRS4984|fiber cabl|10 |10
08.01.19|DGFE4 |magazine   |1  |5
08.01.19|POIJ48|cleaner    |9  |20
08.01.19|49894U|chair      |5  |100
08.01.19|DF2345|mouse      |5  |20
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |12 |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |8  |1500
08.01.19|HK2345|tablet     |2  |1500
```

Comment: This is a BI question, you are trying to solve with simple query. You want to plot product histogram and decide criteria for picking products. Other wise just think if a product 1 is sold every day but only 1 item but product 2 is sold every other day but 20 items what is the usefulness of product 1 result? you can not give discounts, design supply chain or anything with product 1. so query will give you very obscure results i think. It is similar to recommendor system problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on `Product` and sort on the number of days with sales (`count(distinct Date)`):

```
select  Procuct
,       count(distinct Date) as NumberOfDaysWithSales
,       sum(Qty) as TotalSold
,       sum(Qty*Price) as TotalRevenue
from    YourTable
group by
        Product
order by
        count(distinct Date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "most popular" product by number of days in the data, I would expect a query like this:

```
select top (1) with ties product, count(distinct date) as num_days
from t
group by product
order by num_days desc;
```

The `with ties` takes into account that multiple products may both have the same popularity by this measure.  If you wanted to break ties by the total number of products, then:

```
select top (1) with ties product,
       count(distinct date) as num_days,
       sum(qty) as total_qty
from t
group by product
order by num_days desc, total_qty desc;
```

Once again, there could still be ties.